# ¿Cómo comparar contraseña encriptada con la que introduce el usuario en el login?

Tags: java

¿Qué tengo que hacer para comparar la contraseña introducida con la que esta encriptada en la base de datos? He debuggueado y cada vez que inserto la misma contraseña en el login, al encriptarla el resultado que me da es diferente, es eso posible? Os pongo el registro y el login, cada uno esta hecho en un servlet distinto.

Cuando le das al botón `submit` del registro vienes aqui:

**servletRegistro**

```
 String pagina = "main.jsp";
    User user = new User();
    UserBO uBO = new UserBO();  

    String nombreUser= request.getParameter("user");
    String correo = request.getParameter("mail");
    String passd = request.getParameter("pass");
    String repassd = request.getParameter("repitPass");

    boolean userRep = Security.userExist(nombreUser);//compruebo si existe el user
    boolean mailRep = Security.mailExist(correo);//compruebo si exista el mail
    boolean passNoCoincidens = Security.passComprovation(passd, repassd);//compruebo si el pass coincide con el 
                                                                        //campo "introduce de nuevo la contraseña"

    if(userRep||mailRep||passNoCoincidens) {

        request.setAttribute("error", "hay algun error en los datos introducidos");
        pagina = "registro.jsp";
        request.getRequestDispatcher(pagina).forward(request, response);

    }else {

        user.setUsuario(nombreUser.trim());
        user.setMail(correo.trim());
        user.setPass(Security.encrypt(passd.trim()));//introduzco en el usuario 
                                                    //la contraseña a la vez que la encripto

        user = uBO.alta(user);
        request.setAttribute("usuario", user);
        request.getRequestDispatcher(pagina).forward(request, response);
    }
```

**metodo encryptar**

```
    public static String encrypt(String pass) {
    MessageDigest md = null;

    byte[] passByte = null;


    try {
        passByte = pass.getBytes("UTF-8");
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    byte[] converPass = md.digest(passByte);

    String passCifrado = converPass.toString();

    return passCifrado;
}
```

Como decía, cada vez que encripto la misma contraseña, `passCifrado` siempre es defirente, deberia ser el mismo, no? pues la pass es la misma.

**Login Servlet:**

```
     String pagina = "main.jsp";
    User u = new User();
    UserBO uBO = new UserBO();

    String nombreUser= request.getParameter("user");
    String passd = request.getParameter("pass");


    boolean validUser = Security.userValidation(nombreUser.trim(), Security.encrypt(passd.trim()));//compruebo si el user existe en la bbdd
    //el metodo userValidation me devuelve true si el usuario existe y false sino.


    if(validUser) {
        u.setUsuario(nombreUser.trim()); //itroduzco el nombre de usuario en el Objeto usuario
        u.setPass(Security.encrypt(passd.trim()));//itroduzco la contraseña de usuario en el Objeto usuario a la vez que se encripta
        u = uBO.recuperarUserValidado(u);

        request.setAttribute("usuario", u);
        request.getRequestDispatcher(pagina).forward(request, response);

    }else {

        pagina = "login.jsp";
        request.setAttribute("error", "hay algun error en los datos introducidosel usuario no existe");
        request.getRequestDispatcher(pagina).forward(request, response);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás guardando la posición en memoria del objeto. Seguramente te aparece algo como `[B@58fe210a` pero eso no es el resultado que deseas.

Te recomiendo que uses algo así, mejor:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
for (final byte b : converPass) {
    sb.append(String.format("%02x", b));
}
String passCifrado = sb.toString().toUpperCase();
```

Prueba con esto y checa si funciona como quieres.

Comment: no te entiendo, donde tengo que usar eso?  y si, la salida que me sale es del tipo que tu dices [B@....   pero no he entendido que debo de hacer.

Comment: @sergipc88 Ok, deja modifico la respuesta para que sea acorde a tu código.

Comment: vale gracias,perfecto voy a probar

Comment: ya me funciona muchas gracias

Comment: por cierto, dices que es una salida rapida..... entiendo que entonces no es lo mas correcto, como se suele hacer?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que, si te fijas en lo que se guarda, o sea, el `String` que se genera, es algo como `[61, -4, 9, -112, -53, 2, 50, -126, -24, -68, 101, 17, 99, -66, -90, -78]`, entonces, para fines prácticos, eso funciona (si no te importa la cadena que se guarda), pero por lo general un MD5 lo encontrarás como AB12CD34 que es hexadecimal. Entonces se tendría que convertir lo que recibes en la cadena a hexa.

Comment: ha vale, entonces solo faltaria convertir a hexa.

Comment: sabrias como hacerlo?

Comment: @sergipc88 Síp, modificaré la respuesta en un momento.

Comment: dado tu codigo, deveriaa dejar esta linea:   byte[] converPass = md.digest(passByte);

Comment: @sergipc88 Sí es correcto, deja la línea que mencionas, si no, no tendrías la "digestion" que necesitas convertir.

Comment: De acuerdo muchas gracias, man.

Comment: he probado tu codigo y el resultado es el mismo de antes,  lo que obtengo es algo asi [74, 57, 99, -81, 25, -15, 96, -44, -9, -44, -79, -79, -47, -99, 36, 25]

Comment: es correcto que obtenga algo asi?

Comment: @sergipc88 No, no es correcto, debería ser algo así: `3DFC0990CB023282E8BC651163BEA6B2`. Asegúrate de que estás usando bien esta parte `String passCifrado = sb.toString().toUpperCase();`

Comment: si si, ya me funciona perfectamente muchas gracias.´ por cierto tengo otra pregunta sobre este projecto, no se si crear otra pregunta o donde hacerla.

Comment: @sergipc88 Crea otra pregunta para tu otra duda. Procura no mezclar preguntas en un solo post. ¡Saludos!